WKWebView's property isInspectable=true not work
On macOS， If WKWebView is subchild of NSViewController that shows by presentAsModalWindow function, the property of WKWebView "isInspectable=true" will not work by Safari!
Why does this problem happen? Is it a bug for macOS？
